# How do programs output to elsewhere than STDOUT/STDERR? How to avoid it?

Tags: bash, terminal, io-redirection

Apparently I don't know all the output destinations that are available for use. I know about `stdout`(`&1`) and `stderr` (`&2`). However, after redirecting both descriptors, I sometimes *still* get some output in my console!

The easiest example I can think of is GNU Parallel; Each time I use it, I see a citation notice. Even when I do `&2>1 > file`, I still see the notice.

And the same applies to `emerge`: When I run emerge and there are some problems, some informations aren't printed to `stdout` nor `stdin`, since I redirect them and they still get through.

I mostly solve these problems by using `script`, but I am still wondering what's causing this issue.

Comment: Please provide a *full* example.

Comment: which shell? have a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash

Comment: I don't really understand the downvote, but it looks like my case is exactly the FAQ thing. @spasic would you care to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Is `&2>1 > file` exactly what you typed?  It _should_ be `>file 2>&1` to do what you want.  What you typed will do something completely different (background the main command, to start with!).  Order of operation is also important; redirect `stdout` _before_ `stderr`.

Comment: @StephenHarris see my previous comment - yes, it is, and I suspect that this is excatly the problem.

Comment: You won't get them _all_.  A script can always write to `/dev/tty`.

Comment: @MatthewRock tbh, I don't have clear understanding as well.. if your problem has been solved using that FAQ, you can post an answer yourself explaining problem and solution.. with a link to that FAQ

Comment: As for GNU `parallel`: `mkdir ~/.parallel; touch ~/.parallel/will-cite` will disable the annoying message. Alternatively, look around for other implementations of `parallel`.

Comment: Why not do as GNU Parallel suggests? Run 'parallel --citation' once.

Comment: @OleTange Because it isn't a problem - I'm asking why something is happening and I'm using `parallel` as an example.

Comment: @MatthewRock this is an additional info. I feel like Ole answered to Sato maybe?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The syntax you used is wrong.

```
cmd &2>1 >file
```

will be split down as

```
cmd &
2>1 >file
```

This will:

1. Run `cmd` as a background job with no redirections
2. In a separate process (without a command!) will redirect `stderr` to a file literally called `1` and redirect `stdout` to `file`

The syntax you want is:

```
cmd >file 2>&1
```

The order of operations is important.  This will:

1. Redirect `stdout` to `file`
2. Redirect `stderr` to `&1` - ie the same filehandle as `stdout`

The result is that both `stderr` and `stdout` will be redirected to `file`.

In `bash`, a simpler non-standard (and so I don't recommend it, on portability grounds) syntax of `cmd &> file` does the same thing.

Comment: Nice, thanks. The other problem might be `/dev/tty`, but hopefully this doesn't happen too often(if at all).

Comment: If you have the `at` command on your machine and have privileges to use it, then you can run the command via `at now`.  See the manpage for details.  This will run the command via a batch process mechanism and the process will never have a tty to write to.  But, in general, I wouldn't worry about this edge case.  Typically only processes requiring interaction and deliberately need to display things to users despite redirection will use `/dev/tty`.

Comment: been there, done that

Answer (score 13):

There are two problems.

The first one is that the order matters, the second one is `/dev/tty`.

Let's use this script as an example script that we want to capture output from:

`test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo dada
echo edada 1>&2
echo ttdada >/dev/tty
```

Now let's see the outputs of the commands:

`./testmyscript.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null`:

```
edada
ttdada
```

Because the order of evaluation is from left to right, we first get "redirect `stderr` to wherever `stdout` is outputting(so, console output)". Then we get "redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null`. We end up with situation like this:

`stdout` -> `/dev/null`
`stderr` -> console

So we get it right:

`./testmyscript.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`

And we get:

`ttdada`.

Now we do "Redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null`", and then "Redirect stderr to where stdout is pointing"(so, `/dev/null`). Hurray!

However, we still have a problem; program prints to `/dev/tty`. Now I don't know how to fix this kind of behaviour, so you're most likely going to need `script`, but hopefully this behaviour won't happen too often.

Comment: how do you, redirect output from `/dev/tty` using `script`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right about /dev/tty.  I'm having that problem with the partclone.* family of commands, which output timing information to /dev/tty.  The --quiet option says it disables it, but that does not seem to work.