# Redirection of output results in an empty file

Tags: shell-script, pipe, io-redirection

I have a shell script that I should preferably not be editing but that I would have to use the output of. Doing `./SomeScript.sh -d` displays the output I need on the shell.

However, I get an empty file if I try to redirect the output.

```
./SomeScript.sh -d > temp 
cat temp
```

After checking [Why redirecting output sometimes produces an empty file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586443/why-redirecting-output-sometimes-produces-an-empty-file), I have also tried `echo $(./SomeScript.sh -d)` but the command prints nothing.

Initially I was trying to `grep` a line from the output, but after realising that nothing was returned, I tried to redirect the output to a file instead and realised this problem. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Is there an empty line at the end of the script? What does 
    ./SomeScript.sh -d >> temp
do?

Comment: If you're talking about the `temp` script where the output was redirected to, yes, there's one empty line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`script -c "./SomeScript.sh -flags" temp`

This command worked for me but I'm not too sure why either.

Comment: Possibly the script [prints to `/dev/tty`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297112/108618).

Answer (score 1):

If `./SomeScript.sh -d > temp` results in an empty file (and yet you can see the output on the screen), that means that the program is maybe printing to stderr instead of stout. So, try redirecting its stderr too -- i.e., use this:

```
./SomeScript.sh -d >temp 2>&1
```

Or you could send the outputs to two separate files:

```
./myScript  1>outtemp 2>errtemp
```

Comment: This might be the solution for some others so thanks for the answer, but it's not the case here.

Comment: Have you looked inside that script to see if it's doing some funny stuff? Can you paste it someplace where we can see it?

Comment: it's very long and calls other functions, but one possible cause might be that the echo commands are being passed to named pipes (tbh, I'm not familiar with named pipes) instead of being directly invoked by the script

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
./SomeScript.sh -d >> temp
```

this will append each line of the script, rather than write and overwrite line by line.

Edit: try

```
./SomeScript.sh -d &>> temp
```

if you want to redirect stderr as well as stdout.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Hmmm, it worked on my machine (famous last words, I know). Could you post the contents of SomeScript.sh perhaps, if it's not too long?

Comment: I know sharing the script would really help, but unfortunately it's really long and proprietary so I won't be able to

Comment: If it's "proprietary", then you're in the wrong place. We can't tell you why something we can't see is not working.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue and came for this workaround:

`./SomeScript.sh -d | tee temp.txt`

Hope it saves you time!

Comment: If redirecting the standar output stream does not work, it's because the data is either delivered on the standard error stream or directly to the terminal device. Piping to `tee` would not help.

Comment: Well, that doesn't seem to be the only reason. I have the same problem, the output can be displayed on the terminal but can't be redirected to a file and I have tried the previous answers but got nothing. Using `tee` solved my problem.