# How to redirect output from /dev/tty to /dev/null?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, tty

I have an executable script `hello` containing the following code,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello" > /dev/tty
```

I want to redirect it's output to `/dev/null`.

```
./hello > /dev/null 2>&1
```

doesn't work, because it redirects only `stdout` and `stderr`.

I found two answers, claiming that this can be done using `script` command, but they doesn't explain how.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297237/421466

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296108/421466

Or is there any other way to suppress its output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### changing the script

Assuming file descriptor 3 is not used yet:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>/dev/tty
#exec 3>/dev/null
echo "hello" >&3
```

You open fd 3 to `/dev/tty` or `/dev/null`, easy to switch. Then you replace all `> /dev/tty` with `>&3`.

### not changing the script

A solution outside the script would be to create a mount namespace (`man unshare`), execute `mount --bind /dev/null /dev/tty` in it and then run the unmodified script there.

Comment: +1 Great answer. I wasn't aware of the consequence of not using a mount namespace and I ran the `mount` command directly. Doing so rendered `sudo` command useless and I couldn't `umount /dev/tty` because it required sudo privilage. Thankfully I was experimenting on a virtual machine :).